# Can we have something like this big SO RegEx popup for Font ID / critique questions?

Tags: feature-request

I was just writing a question on StackOverflow about regular expressions, and a big popup came up while I was typing.

**Unlike tag alerts,** which we've discussed, it didn't depend on me choosing a tag, and it was huge, with lots of detailed steps for me to try.

[image]

It looks like exactly what we want for font ID and critique questions.

What is it?

Can we have one?

---

*(but in our nice colours, not "I shouldn't have eaten that burrito" yellow)*

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific key word that comes up in titles for this kind of question?

We don't want to pop this up for every question that has "font" in the title, but not all of the ones we do want have "identif*" in them, either.

*Most* critique questions use the word critique in the title, but it's probable that the ones that don't are the ones asked by that most need to see this popup. They haven't even realized yet that their question is really a critique request. ([Example 1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41351/1976), [example 2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/45653/1976)... there are more like this--bad questions where the user didn't even think to use the critique *tag*, let alone put it in their title.)

Comment: Hmm, I'd bet that 90%+ of questions with titles containing "what" and "font" are font ID, maybe someone with better search-fu can test that theory. How sophisticated can the rule be?

Comment: @user568458: how sophisticated? it probably uses regex! :)

Comment: @yorik I see what you did there...